# parse a path like and an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path, argparse

I have this script in python 3.7:

```
pars = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='copy dirs script', description="à copier MSRE localment:",
                               epilog="Comme ça on copie les repertoires")

pars.add_argument("-o", "--output", action='store_const', default=destination_file,
                         const=destination_file1, 
                       help="the destination dirctory is the curently working dirctory")
pars.add_argument("-a", "--arch", choices=("all", "i386", "x86_64"), type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="Targeted check architecture: 32b, 64b, All")
pars.add_argument("-p", "--platform", choices=("all", "windows", "linux"), type = lambda s : s.lower(),
                       help="Targeted check platform: Windows, Linux, All")
args = pars.parse_args()
```

I want to parse the output in the command line, for example:

```
python script.py -o C:/Users/michael/Documents/install -a all -p windows
```

I don't know how to store the output into a variable.
How can I proceed?

Comment: Which output do you want to store into a variable? The output of this program when you call `--help`? The output of the program itself? The command-line input? I don't think we can help unless you're more specific on what you need us to do.

Comment: I want to store the path i gave to program to be stored into a variable

python script.py -o C:/Users/michael/Documents/install -a all -p windows,

C:/Users/michael/Documents/install to be stored into avariable when i run the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can access the arguments using:

As you suggested in comment all you want is to access **--output** or **-o** change your add_argument for output to something like i added below

```python
    pars.add_argument("-o", "--output", default=destination_file, 
                       help="the destination dirctory is the curently working dirctory")
    platform = args.platform
    architecture = args.arch
    output = args.output
```

so on and so forth, for any other arguments you want to access should be available in args variable. Go through the documentation for more info
[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#example)

Comment: i did this, in fact i just want to take the argument "C:/Users/michael/Documents/install" and to store it into a variable when i run the program, this is the exaple:
-o C:/Users/michael/Documents/install -a all -p windows

Comment: then just use the 3rd line from my example where i create an variable output, that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dictionary of the args passed by using `vars(args)`. `args.parse_args()` returns a [Namespace object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace)  and you can then use `vars(args)` on it in order to get a dictionary. Use https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html to learn about manipulating a dict. 
Other answer is probably better if you don't want to learn about dicts or want to keep it simple :)